# Java Android, Default textview color is grey, looks like hint text color, how to correct it?

Tags: java, android, textview

Text color is grey as shown below, i have not set any default color in sytles.xml.
As you can see there is a difference between the spinner text color and the textview color.

[color difference between Spinner and textview text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOHrQ.png)

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView color"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:padding="12dp"    />


    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="192dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:entries="@array/spinner_items"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"

         />
```

I ran the `ColorStateList oldColors =  textView.getTextColors();` i got the below result.

```
ColorStateList{mThemeAttrs=nullmChangingConfigurations=0mStateSpecs=[[-16842910], []]mColors=[603979776, -1979711488]mDefaultColor=-1979711488}
```

Is the text color is due to this style, my Styles.xml:

```
 <resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

All i want is regular black for texts. And i don't want to add change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Add color property in your TextView

<TextView
          **android:color="#000000"**
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="TextView color"
          android:textAlignment="gravity"
          android:textAllCaps="false"
          android:textSize="16dp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:gravity="left|center"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
          android:padding="12dp"    />

Comment: Thanks, i added the  **android:color="#000000"**  still i am getting the issue.

Comment: remove your style="" property if u added custom style to text

Comment: I have not set any style, this is my styles.xml:  '<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
 <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that is the default color of text. So i have to force it to use regular black in  Styles.xml

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/textColorPrimaryLight</item>
```

The reason i was looking for is i want to implement Dark mode. Below article helped my issue. Basically i have to use 2 styles.xml to implement dark mode.

[How to officially support Dark Mode in your apps?](https://medium.com/@phamduy.uit/android-10-to-be-ready-for-the-dark-mode-f8113dec9ea0)